# One rails app, one machine, several databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm writing a rails app that is not intended to act as a web server; I only want to use it to manipulate the database easily.  The same application can be used to manipulate many databases on one machine.

This situation is quite similar to git; one git app, one machine, and several git repositories.

I am using sqlite3.

Rails has only one `config/database.yml` per app.  I'm looking for a way to switch between `config/database.yml`'s for each of my app's repositories.  In git, you switch repositories by changing the current directory.  For my app, any alternative to achieve this 'swapping' of `config/database.yml` is OK for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here.  If you want to load different environments (thus loading different databases), you can achieve this with, for example, `rails c -e environment` where `environment` is the database and environment you want rails to load (e.g. development, production, test)

Comment: Thanks for your question; "rails console -e environment" just switches database entry written in config/database.yml.  I would like to have several production databases (e.g. prod1, prod2, ...) for any directory in my machine to swtich database; this is similar to git repository; one git app, one machine, and serveral repositories.